# Struggled to find a cause of redirecting on the error page while requesting a token from Spring Cloud Authentication Server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I've got a problem with a spring cloud auth server. I sent a request from spring cloud gateway service and auth server received and authenticated user but it's redirected me on the error page.
**Here is a spring cloud gateway application.yaml file**

```
server:
  port: 9090

spring:
  application:
    name: api-gateway
  jackson:
    deserialization:
      FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES: false
    serialization:
      INDENT_OUTPUT: false
      WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS: false
      WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN: true
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          insta-client-oidc:
            client-id: insta-client
            client-secret: secret
            scope: openid
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri-template: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/insta-client-oidc'
            client-authentication-method: client_secret_post
            client-name: insta-client-oidc
        provider:
          insta-client-oidc:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:9000
            token-uri: http://localhost:9000/oauth2/token
            authorization-uri: http://localhost:9000/oauth2/authorize
            user-info-uri: http://localhost:9000/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: user_name
            user-info-authentication-method: form
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:
        - id: user-service-route
          uri: http://localhost:8080 #${USERS_SERVICE_URL:lb://user-service}
          predicates:
            - Path=/public/v1/users
            - Path=/public/v1/users/{username}
            - Path=/public/v1/users/search
            - Path=/public/v1/users/{username}/followers/**
            - Path=/public/v1/users/{username}/followings/**
            - Path=/public/v1/users/{username}/password
            - Path=/public/v1/users/{username}/photo
            - Path=/public/v1/users/{username}/profile
      default-filters:
        - RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
        - TokenRelay=

eureka:
  instance:
    instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${instanceId:${random.value}}
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    enabled: false

management:
  endpoint:
    gateway:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: gateway

logging:
  level:
    com: TRACE
    org: TRACE
```

**Here is a spring authentication server config:**

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {
    private final SecurityProperties securityProperties;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        return http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain nextSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         return http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .build();
}

    @Bean
    static BeanFactoryPostProcessor removeErrorSecurityFilter() {
        return (beanFactory) ->
            ((DefaultListableBeanFactory)beanFactory).removeBeanDefinition("errorPageSecurityInterceptor");
}

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
    RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .clientId(securityProperties.getClientId())
            .clientSecret(passwordEncoder.encode(securityProperties.getClientSecret()))
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
            .redirectUri("http://localhost:9090/login/oauth2/code/insta-client-oidc")
            .redirectUri("http://localhost:9090/authorized")
            .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
            .tokenSettings(tokenSettings())
            
//.clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
            .build();

    return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
}

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        RSAKey rsaKey = generateRsa();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);

        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
    }

    private static RSAKey generateRsa() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();

        return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
            .privateKey(privateKey)
            .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .build();
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);

        return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    }

    @Bean
    public ProviderSettings providerSettings() {
        return ProviderSettings.builder().issuer("http://localhost:9000").build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> tokenCustomizer() {
        return context -> {
        Authentication principal = context.getPrincipal();
        if (Objects.equals(context.getTokenType().getValue(), "access_token") && principal instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) {
            Set<String> authorities = principal.getAuthorities().stream()
                    .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toSet());
            context.getClaims().claim("authorities", authorities);
            }
        };
    }

    private TokenSettings tokenSettings() {
        return TokenSettings.builder()
            .accessTokenFormat(OAuth2TokenFormat.SELF_CONTAINED)
            .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofMinutes(securityProperties.getExpirationTimeInMinutes()))
            .idTokenSignatureAlgorithm(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256)
            .build();
    }
}
```

***Whole project you can find here: https://github.com/ZhenyaShvyrkov/insta-copy***

***log file you also can find in github repository***

Thank you for any help in advance. Have a good one!

Comment: have you found a solution on this ?

Comment: Unfortunately, i havent.
Maybe in new versions it's already fixed